# Why does my server freeze everyday at the same time?

Tags: server, command-line, kernel, log

My server freezes every day at 00:50 am. I do not know what it can be. In log files I found just such a suspect listing, but I do not know what that means. Could someone help me??

```
kernel: php5-cgi invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x84d0, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
kernel: php5-cgi cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
kernel: Pid: 20316, comm: php5-cgi Not tainted 2.6.38.2-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #2
kernel: Call Trace:
kernel: [<ffffffff810de9e8>] ? dump_header+0x88/0x1d0
kernel: [<ffffffff810aa6e3>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xb3/0xe0
kernel: [<ffffffff810de931>] ? oom_unkillable_task+0x91/0xc0
kernel: [<ffffffff8150c7e5>] ? ___ratelimit+0xa5/0x120
kernel: [<ffffffff810def0c>] ? oom_kill_process+0x8c/0x2e0
kernel: [<ffffffff810dedd3>] ? select_bad_process+0x93/0x140
kernel: [<ffffffff810df398>] ? out_of_memory+0x238/0x3e0
kernel: [<ffffffff810e45bd>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x86d/0x8a0
kernel: [<ffffffff8110ff4a>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xaa/0x120
kernel: [<ffffffff81069d46>] ? pte_alloc_one+0x16/0x40
kernel: [<ffffffff810fa159>] ? __pte_alloc+0x29/0xd0
kernel: [<ffffffff810fa363>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x163/0x200
kernel: [<ffffffff81066077>] ? do_page_fault+0x197/0x410
kernel: [<ffffffff81100556>] ? do_brk+0x286/0x390
kernel: [<ffffffff81a7419f>] ? page_fault+0x1f/0x30
kernel: Mem-Info:
kernel: Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
kernel: CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
kernel: Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 156
kernel: active_anon:468626 inactive_anon:383 isolated_anon:0
kernel: active_file:66 inactive_file:101 isolated_file:64
kernel: unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
kernel: free:3426 slab_reclaimable:1691 slab_unreclaimable:13557
kernel: mapped:380 shmem:404 pagetables:10150 bounce:0
kernel: Node 0 DMA free:7932kB min:44kB low:52kB high:64kB active_anon:7056kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15684kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:388kB kernel_stack:16kB pagetables:488kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no 
 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1967 1967 1967
kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:5772kB min:5648kB low:7060kB high:8472kB active_anon:1867448kB inactive_anon:1532kB active_file:264kB inactive_file:404kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):256kB present:2014316kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:1520kB shmem:1616kB slab_reclaimable:6764kB slab_unreclaimable:53840kB kernel_stack:1912kB pagetables:40112kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:1423 all_unreclaimable? no
kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
kernel: Node 0 DMA: 45*4kB 56*8kB 29*16kB 8*32kB 7*64kB 4*128kB 2*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 7940kB
kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 149*4kB 1*8kB 1*16kB 1*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 5772kB
kernel: 646 total pagecache pages
kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
kernel: Total swap = 0kB
kernel: 515824 pages RAM
kernel: 12393 pages reserved
kernel: 310091 pages shared
kernel: 436769 pages non-shared
kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
kernel: [ 1562]     0  1562     4238       40   0       0             0 upstart-udev-br
kernel: [ 1564]     0  1564     4230       74   0     -17         -1000 udevd
kernel: [ 1656]     0  1656     4229       75   0     -17         -1000 udevd
kernel: [ 1661]     0  1661     4229       73   0     -17         -1000 udevd
kernel: [ 2620]     0  2620    12328      141   0     -17         -1000 sshd
kernel: [ 2631]   101  2631    13713      221   0       0             0 rsyslogd
kernel: [ 2648]     0  2648     1532       30   0       0             0 getty
kernel: [ 2652]     0  2652     1532       29   0       0             0 getty
kernel: [ 2655]     0  2655     1532       29   0       0             0 getty
kernel: [ 2656]     0  2656     1532       29   0       0             0 getty
kernel: [ 2659]     0  2659     1532       30   0       0             0 getty
kernel: [ 2666]     0  2666     5281       65   0       0             0 cron
kernel: [ 2701]   102  2701    32660     5339   0       0             0 named
kernel: [ 2708]   104  2708    63627    11103   0       0             0 mysqld
kernel: [ 2723]     0  2723     3482       38   0       0             0 couriertcpd
kernel: [ 2725]     0  2725      980       17   0       0             0 courierlogger
kernel: [ 2735]     0  2735     3482       38   0       0             0 couriertcpd
kernel: [ 2737]     0  2737      980       17   0       0             0 courierlogger
kernel: [ 2744]     0  2744     3482       41   0       0             0 couriertcpd
kernel: [ 2747]     0  2747     1013       26   0       0             0 courierlogger
kernel: [ 2754]     0  2754     3482       38   0       0             0 couriertcpd
kernel: [ 2757]     0  2757      980       18   0       0             0 courierlogger
kernel: [ 3313] 65534  3313    15729       79   0       0             0 memcached
kernel: [ 3383]  1002  3383    12937     1590   0       0             0 sw-cp-serverd
kernel: [ 3393]     0  3393     4894       58   0       0             0 xinetd
kernel: [ 3535]  2522  3535     1027       28   0       0             0 qmail-send
kernel: [ 3536]  2022  3536     1015       26   0       0             0 splogger
kernel: [ 3537]     0  3537     1025       33   0       0             0 qmail-lspawn
kernel: [ 3538]  2521  3538     1025       17   0       0             0 qmail-rspawn
kernel: [ 3539]  2520  3539     1014       22   0       0             0 qmail-clean
kernel: [ 3621]     0  3621    68797     3424   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [ 3622]     0  3622    40565     1745   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [ 3922]   106  3922    40087    38746   0       0             0 drwebd.real
kernel: [ 3985]     0  3985     3163       37   0       0             0 mdadm
kernel: [ 4024]     0  4024     1532       30   0       0             0 getty
kernel: [24625]     0 24625    28299    11913   0       0             0 spamd
kernel: [24626]   110 24626    28299    11912   0       0             0 spamd
kernel: [24628]   110 24628    28299    11912   0       0             0 spamd
kernel: [12008]    33 12008    68960     3226   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [12016]    33 12016    68946     3232   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [12568]    33 12568    68952     3229   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [13362]    33 13362    68933     3220   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [16894]    33 16894    68946     3204   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [16895]    33 16895    68902     3189   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [18991]   106 18991    40087    38745   0       0             0 drwebd.real
kernel: [18992]   106 18992    40087    38745   0       0             0 drwebd.real
kernel: [18993]   106 18993    40087    38745   0       0             0 drwebd.real
kernel: [18994]   106 18994    40087    38745   0       0             0 drwebd.real
kernel: [19165]    33 19165    68995     3216   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [19178]    33 19178    68947     3225   0       0             0 apache2
kernel: [19918]    33 19918    68961     3218   0       0             0 apache2
```

If you need more information, write me.

Domaneni

Comment: When the server freezes you can ping the machine and SSH into it remotely?

Comment: Can you set up a cronjob to dump `ps -A|grep "php5"`  at 0:49:59? Also, does PHP do anything, to your knowledge, at that time? You could consider migrating to ServerFault.se if few answers arrive  here.

Comment: @CeltaWeb: I can ping server, but ssh don't function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution was reported here: http://www.hskupin.info/2010/06/17/how-to-fix-the-oom-killer-crashe-under-linux/

> So what’s happened? The reason can be explained shortly: The Linux
>   kernel likes to always allocate memory if applications asking for it.
>   Per default it doesn’t really check if there is enough memory
>   available. Given that behavior applications can allocate more memory
>   as really is available. At some point it can definitely cause an out
>   of memory situation. As result the OOM killer will be invoked and will
>   kill that process:
>
> ```
> Jun 11 11:35:21 vsrv03 kernel: [378878.356858] php-cgi invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1280d2, order=0, oomkilladj=0
> Jun 11 11:36:11 vsrv03 kernel: [378878.356880] Pid: 8490, comm: php-cgi Not tainted 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64 #1
> ```
>
> The downside of this action is that all other running processes are
>   also affected. As result the complete VM didn’t work and needed a
>   restart.
>
> **To fix this problem** the behavior of the kernel has to be changed, so
>   it will no longer overcommit the memory for application requests.
>   Finally I have included those mentioned values into the
>   /etc/sysctl.conf file, so they get automatically applied on start-up:
>
> ```
> vm.overcommit_memory = 2
> vm.overcommit_ratio = 80
> ```

(Reboot to apply changes.)

More about overcommit: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html#ss9.6

Comment: So these two lines will solve the problem??

Comment: I haven't tested it, I was hoping you would and let us know. :)

Comment: I tried it and so far the server without falling. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What happens is simple, the why is not (need more information).

`php5-cgi` begins to use a LOT of memory at that time (may be a memory leak or a side effect), so much so that the system will run out of memory. So the kernel kills it (`oom-killer` is the kernel's out-of-memory killer) to maintain system stability.

This looks like a VPS -- is it? What kind? OOM errors are usually rare on physical machines with sufficient (1 GB+) RAM and swap space (2x RAM at least).

Comment: It is dedicate server Kimsufi 2G: http://www.kimsufi.co.uk/. RAM is 2GB and Processor is Intel Atom 1.20+ GHz.

Comment: @ZbyněkNedoma: thank you, I will look at your log in detail in a few hours and try to figure more out. What is php5-cgi doing at or just before 00:50? Something is triggering it...

Comment: In syslog I found this:  
`drwebd.real: Loading /var/drweb/bases/drwnasty.vdb - Ok, virus records: 28348  
drwebd.real: Total virus records: 3473166  
drwebd.real: Key file: /opt/drweb/drweb32.key - Key file was not found! (No such file or directory)  
drwebd.real: A path to a valid license key file was not specified.  
drwebd.real: Daemon is enabled for protecting 0 e-mails:  
drwebd.real: Daemon is installed, active interfaces: /var/drweb/run/.daemon  127.0.0.1:3000  
CRON[20081]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 8 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null) ..... Repeat this about 20 times  
`